# How to Go to home screen when pressed on navbar button

Tags: iphone

I want to add a rightbar button on navigation bar as home button..

When ever i tap on that button i want to go to firstcontroller,that is my home screen

Please help me in this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is very, very misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This to go to HomeScreen in navBar, first create rightBar button

```
{
    UIBarButtonItem *Button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(Button_Action)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = Button;
    [Button release];
}

-(void) Button_Action
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the response....I have created another custom view and placed that view on my navigation bar,So now i am adding button to that view.so now can i go to the controller which i want,when i tap on that button

Answer (score 1):

If your application is navigation based app then use following line of code in your button's IBAction.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```